# Call presentModalViewController from NSObject class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

In my subclass of `NSObject` I would like to call something like

```
    [[self navController] presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

But none of my tries were successful. How can I call a modal view if I'm not in a subclass of `UIViewController`?

**Solution:**

```
#import "myProjectNameAppDelegate.h"
// ...
MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
myProjectNameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myProjectNameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[appDelegate navController] presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to display a modal view without a ViewController. You have to store a reference to a UIViewController in your class so you can access it. Or setup a property in your AppDelegate, which you can get by calling [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: I have a property in my `AppDelegate` called "navController". Why can't I access `  [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] navController] presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];` Do I have to declare another property and set this property to `self` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?

Comment: You should be able to access it directly as you pasted, does it work?

Comment: No, I get "'UIApplication' may not respond to '-navController'". With `delegate` I get "'-navController' not found in protocol(s)"

Comment: You need to cast your app delegate to your real delegate.

Comment: How does this work? I know something like `AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` but what is "AppDelegate"? Then I could do `[[appDelegate navController] presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];`?

Comment: I'm such a noob. OK the "AppDelegate" is the AppDelegate in my project. It is called something like "myProjectNameAppDelegate". I post the solution in my question.

Comment: It's OK being a noob, as long as you learn ;-) Glad to be helpful there.

Answer (score 7):

better way to call a presentModalViewController is, passing `viewcontroller` to the `NSobject` class. call the `nsobject` function from the `uiviewcontroller`
Here is the code with mail example

In view Controller //your current view

`[nsobjectclassObject OpenMailComposer:self];` //this will take the viewcontroller to `NSobject` class

In NSObject class //may be sharing class

```
-(void)OpenMailComposer:(UIViewController*)view
{

    viewControllertoShow = view; // viewControllertoShow is UIVIewcontroller object
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailView setSubject:@"Hey! check this out!"];
  [viewControllertoShow presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
}
```

For dismissing from `NSObject class` you can do the following

`[viewControllertoShow dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

If you hold the navigationController or some viewController, you can present a modal view controller.

What is your `myView`? Is it a view, is it a viewController. I hope that it is a viewcontroller otherwise, this is the reason your code doesn't run

Comment: `myView` is a ViewController. `MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];` But I can't call the modal view from the same ViewController (tried that, but nothing happens). I can't access the NavigationController because I'm in a 'NSObject' class. I get "xxx may not respond to xxx" warning.

Comment: then, it makes sense that you cannot access navController. So, the good way is when you init your object, pass it a view Controller: `MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] initWithViewController:myViewController];` then store your myViewController somewhere

Comment: When you need to presentModalViewController do: `[myViewController presentModalViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: I tried to find a solution for getting a ViewController reference. But I only thought about getting a property, which would include a new instantiation. Your solution would work. Thanks for that! I marked jv42 as solution, because I don't have to change two `NSObject` classes (add two init methods and change calls).

Comment: ok, you are welcome. you can also vote up as well if you think that helps:)